# How do I recalculate a variable on-click in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Hi I think this is an easy question, but I'm not sure I'm asking it in the right way for searches. I'm creating a subnav that when clicked scrolls to the appropriate place on the page. To accomplish this I wrote a script that gets the height of the  above where I want to scroll, stores it as a variable and then scrolls the page the variable amount when the user clicks on the subnav. This is a template and the top div changes heights from page to page. This works great, until I start to unfold some accordions. Since the variable is defined when the page loads, it doesn't account for unfolded accordions. How do I make my script recalculate the variables each time the user clicks the button.

Here is how I'm getting the variable

```
    var firstDivHeight = $(".pageStart").height()+250;
```

This code is attached to the subnav and scrolls the page to the correct place on click. When this button is clicked, I'd like it to recalculate the variable.

```
$('.sbmOne').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: firstDivHeight}, 'slow');
    return false;   });
```

Comment: recalculate it the same way you did to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the calculation in your click handler so you recalculate it each time before you use it:

```
$('.sbmOne').click(function() {
    var firstDivHeight = $(".pageStart").height()+250;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: firstDivHeight}, 'slow');
    return false;   
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess I was thinking it had to be more complex than that. This works awesome!